# DocuSign API - How do I make the signer receives a copy of the signed document

Tags: docusignapi

I have this thing working for like 2 years. Then it stopped sending emails to the signers after they signed a document. By the way the document is created from a widget embedded method.

I'm using the PHP SDK of the docusign API. And here's a summary of my code

```
$envelopeApi = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$document = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
$document->setDocumentBase64("My document template");
$document->setName("My template name);
$document->setDocumentId("randomly generated document ID");

// creates the sign here
$signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$signHere->setAnchorString("Signature:");
$signHere->setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent("false");
$signHere->setAnchorUnits("pixels");
$signHere->setAnchorYOffset("50");
$signHere->setAnchorXOffset("5");
$signHere->setDocumentId("The document ID");
$signHere->setRecipientId("The recipient ID, randomly generated");

// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));

// add the signer to the envelope
$signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
$signer->setName("Recipient Name");
$signer->setEmail("Recipient Email");
$signer->setRecipientId("The recipient ID");
$signer->setTabs($tabs);
$signer->setClientUserId("The client user ID");

// Add a recipient to sign the document
$recipients = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners(array($signer));
$envelop_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("Mail subject");

// set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");
$envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
$envelop_definition->setDocuments(array($document));

// create and send the envelope! (aka signature request)
$envelopeApi->createEnvelope("Owner account ID", $envelop_definition, null);
```

I knew that by adding the envelope definition status "sent" would send a copy to the signer but thats not the case. Did something happened recently on the API that I have to adapt? I checked the documentation but still the same. So I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By setting a ClientUserId for your signer, you are creating a Captive Recipient. If you want DocuSign to do email delivery, remove the ClientUserId parameter and a Remote Recipient will be created instead.

Comment: I tried doing this however the result is that  you can't sign the embedded document running on an iframe. ClientUserId seems to be required for it to work as an embed signer.